# How to commit as a part of shared user group in cvs

Tags: cvs

Each time I check out **my_repo** repository to my home folder, the user and the group of the repository becomes as follows:

```
drwxrwxr-x. 8 abdullah abdullah    4096 Sep 15 11:49 my_repo
```

For this reason, each time I commit in cvs, I have to update the repository by executing

`chown -R :cvsusers /usr/repo/my_repo/` command

to be it checked out by another users who are the members of **cvsusers** 
 group.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Try `find /usr/repo/my_repo -type d | xargs chmod g+s` after executing your `chown -R ...` command.

Comment: It seems working. Thanks for your help.